# Why Python while loop is reseting a local variable counter?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary

It always return me repeated values example:

```
{
    "0": [4886, 7051, 9612, 9613, 4895],
    "1": [4886, 7051, 9612, 9613, 4895],
    "2": [4886, 7051, 9612, 9613, 4895],
    "3": [4886, 7051, 9612, 9613, 4895],
    "4": [4886, 7051, 9612, 9613, 4895]
}
```

I don't know why counter is reseting on the end of nested loop. It should add next products inside each batch instead of starting from start. Please tell me how to fix it? thanks!

```
counter = 0
max_number = 4
batches = {}
batch = [] 
batch_counter = 0
while batch_counter <= max_number:
    while counter <= max_number:
        batch.append(data[counter])
        counter = counter+1

    batches[batch_counter] = batch
    batch_counter = batch_counter+1

batches = json.dumps(batches)
return HttpResponse(batches)
```

Comment: Can you give a sample `data`?

Comment: this is what it return: 
{"0": [4886, 7051, 9612, 9613, 4895], "1": [4886, 7051, 9612, 9613, 4895], "2": [4886, 7051, 9612, 9613, 4895], "3": [4886, 7051, 9612, 9613, 4895], "4": [4886, 7051, 9612, 9613, 4895]}
but i want to add next like:
{"0": [4886, 7051, 9612, 9613, 4895], "1": [next ids], "3": [next ids}

Comment: What do you mean "the counter resets"? There's no line in your code where the `counter` variable is set to zero other than the first line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not resetting your `batch` variable after you set it in the inner loop.

```
while batch_counter <= max_number:
    batch = []
    while counter <= max_number:
        ...
```

In your code you initialize batch with a list once. The same list is used to add elements `batch.append(data[counter])`. This list is also added every time with `batches[batch_counter] = batch`.

Comment: Now it returns me json object like this:
{"0": [4886, 7051, 9612, 9613, 4895], "1": [], "2": [], "3": [], "4": []}

Comment: This is because you are looping over all elements in your inner loop: `while counter <= max_number:`. Try changing `max_number` to the number of elements you want in each list. If you want 1 in each list you can remove the loop entirely.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

The reason why this does not work is because **`batch` remains the same list *after* the first iteration**. Once you have constructed the first `batch` list, `counter` is not set to `0` again. As a result the inner `while` loop is never executed again. This is not a problem for Python, because you never instructed Python to remove the `batch` list. So it will simply take the old one, and add that one in the second, third, etc. iteration.

You can solve the problem by **setting the `counter` to `0` and making `batch` a new empty list again**, like:

```
counter = 0
max_number = 4
batches = {}
batch = [] 
batch_counter = 0
while batch_counter <= max_number:
    counter = 0
    batch = []
    while counter <= max_number:
        batch.append(data[counter])
        counter = counter+1

    batches[batch_counter] = batch
    batch_counter = batch_counter+1

batches = json.dumps(batches)
return HttpResponse(batches)
```

You can however make things way more elegant:

```
max_number1 = max_number+1
batch = {i : data[max_number1*i:max_number1*(i+1)] for i in range(max_number1)}
batches = json.dumps(batches)
return HttpResponse(batches)
```

replaces the entire code fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Because your counter reaches to the max_number (inner loop) that's why inner loop executes only once, after that inner loop skipped and you set the same 'batch' in 'batches'.

Comment: After adding:
while ...:
  batch = []
  while.....

it returns me  
 me json object like this: {"0": [4886, 7051, 9612, 9613, 4895], "1": [], "2": [], "3": [], "4": []}

Comment: You should also use different counter for the inner loop and reset after the execution on inner loop, then you program should work.